# Compare dataframes of different length in R and add zeros in the rows that differ

Tags: r, match

I have two data frames (list of names) with different large.

```
v1<-c('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I')
v1=as.data.frame(v1)
```

```
v2<-c('C','D','A','I')
v2=as.data.frame(v2)
```

I need to match both so that the empty rows of the smaller one are filled with 0. So the output should be something like:

```
v3<-c('A',0,'C','D',0,0,0,0,'I')
v3=as.data.frame(v3)
```

I tried using the "match" command but the new data frame had the number of rows of the smallest.

Any ideas???
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `%in%` :

```
v1$v1[!v1$v1 %in% v2$v2] <- 0
v1

#  v1
#1  A
#2  0
#3  C
#4  D
#5  0
#6  0
#7  0
#8  0
#9  I
```

Or with `match` :

```
v1$v1[is.na(match(v1$v1, v2$v2))] <- 0
```

Comment: It is not working for me.. But thanks for the suggestion. In the first option, it changes the v1 but it does not generate a new one. In my case I have "NA" instead of zeros, and I cannot replace them with the command v1[is.na(v1)]<-0 becasue I have the following message: Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, is.na(match(v1$v1, v2$v2)), value = c(1L,  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated. The second option showed the same message and didnt work...

Comment: Do `v1$v1 <- as.character(v1$v1)` and then try again.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `setdiff` as well

```
v1$v1[v1$v1 %in% setdiff(v1$v1, v2$v2)] <- 0
```